# Custom post types category

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy, custom-field

I have created a theme with a custom post type called 'project' and there is a problem. I want to show 5 different custom post type categories on a page in different portions, like posts to show on pages from their respective categories. Is there any solution?

This is my custom post type code with custom taxonomy

```
 <?php
    /**
     * Registers a custom post type.
     */
    function Project_post_type()
    {
        register_post_type(
            'Project',
            array(
    'labels'               => array(
    'name'                => __('Project', 'text_domain'),
    'singular_name'       => __('Project', 'text_domain'),
    'menu_name'           => __('Project', 'text_domain'),
    'name_admin_bar'      => __('Project Item', 'text_domain'),
    'all_items'           => __('All Items', 'text_domain'),
    'add_new'             => _x('Add New', 'prefix_portfolio', 'text_domain'),
    'add_new_item'        => __('Add New Item', 'text_domain'),
    'edit_item'           => __('Edit Item', 'text_domain'),
    'view_item'           => __('View Item', 'text_domain'),
    'search_items'        => __('Search Items', 'text_domain'),
    'not_found'           => __('No items found.', 'text_domain'),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __('No items found in Trash.', 'text_domain'),
    'parent_item_colon'   => __('Parent Items:', 'text_domain'),
                ),
    'public'     => true,
    'menu_position'  => 5,
    'supports'    => array(
                    'title',
                    'editor',
                    'thumbnail',
                    'excerpt',
                    'custom-fields',
                ),
    'taxonomies'   => array(
                    'Project_categories',
                ),

    'menu_icon'   => get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/project-icon.png',
    'has_archive' => true,
    'query_var'  => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
    'slug'    => 'Project',
    ),
    )
   );
    }

    add_action('init', 'Project_post_type');


    /**
     * Registers a custom taxonomy.
     */
    function Project_taxonomy()
    {
        register_taxonomy(
            'Project_categories',
            array(
                'Project',
            ),
    array(
    'labels'               => array(
    'name'                => _x('Categories', 'prefix_portfolio', 'text_domain'),
    'singular_name'       => _x('Category', 'prefix_portfolio', 'text_domain'),
    'menu_name'           => __('Categories', 'text_domain'),
    'all_items'           => __('All Categories', 'text_domain'),
    'edit_item'           => __('Edit Category', 'text_domain'),
    'view_item'           => __('View Category', 'text_domain'),
    'update_item'         => __('Update Category', 'text_domain'),
    'add_new_item'        => __('Add New Category', 'text_domain'),
    'new_item_name'       => __('New Category Name', 'text_domain'),
    'parent_item'         => __('Parent Category', 'text_domain'),
     'parent_item_colon'   => __('Parent Category:', 'text_domain'),
    'search_items'        => __('Search Categories', 'text_domain'),
                ),
    'show_admin_column'    => true,
    'hierarchical'   => true,
   'rewrite'   => array(
  'slug'    => 'portfolio/category',
 ),
)
);
}

add_action('init', 'Project_taxonomy', 0);

function theme_prefix_rewrite_flush() {
flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'theme_prefix_rewrite_flush' );
```

Here is my code to display one category

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'project',
'posts_per_page' => 200, 
'cat' => 'Initiatieffase'
    );
$loop = new WP_Query($args); while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
echo '<li><a href="' . the_permalink() . '">' . the_post_thumbnail() . '</a></li>';
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
```

**EDIT**

This is my new post type function

```
<?php
// Register Custom Post Type
function project_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Projects', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Project', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Project', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'project_post_type', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Project Description', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', ),
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/project-icon.png',
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
    );
    register_post_type( 'project_post_type', $args );

}

// Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'project_post_type', 0 );


// Register Custom Taxonomy
function project_taxonomy() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Projects', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Project', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Project', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Item Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove items', 'text_domain' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used items', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => false,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'project', array( 'post' ), $args );

}

// Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'project_taxonomy', 0 );


function theme_prefix_rewrite_flush() {
flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'theme_prefix_rewrite_flush' );
```

and this is template function

```
<?php
  $args = array(
  'post_type' => 'project',
   'tax_query' => array(
    array(
    'taxonomy' => 'Initiatieffase',
     'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => 'bob'
       )
     )
  );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<li>
 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

but its still showing nothing

---

This is my new post type function

```
<?php
// Register Custom Post Type
function project_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Projects', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Project', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Project', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'project_post_type', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Project Description', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', ),
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/project-icon.png',
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
    );
    register_post_type( 'project_post_type', $args );

}

// Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'project_post_type', 0 );


// Register Custom Taxonomy
function project_taxonomy() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Projects', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Project', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Project', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Item Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove items', 'text_domain' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used items', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => false,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'project', array( 'post' ), $args );

}

// Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'project_taxonomy', 0 );


function theme_prefix_rewrite_flush() {
flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'theme_prefix_rewrite_flush' );
```

and this is template function

```
<?php
  $args = array(
  'post_type' => 'project',
   'tax_query' => array(
    array(
    'taxonomy' => 'Initiatieffase',
     'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => 'bob'
       )
     )
  );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<li>
 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

but its still showing nothing

Comment: Please indent your code properly, half of it is out of screen, making it extremely difficult to read. Thank you

Comment: `cat` should be a category ID, not a name or slug. Also, don't use `wp_reset_query`, you should use `wp_reset_postdata`

Comment: can you give me a code how to use that ? i didn't understand you thanks

Comment: Check out [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for examples. Also make sure that you are using built-in categories. If you are using custom taxonomies, you should be using the `tax_query` parameters, not category parameters

Comment: i tried tax-query it didn't work for me  , and can you send me modified version of this code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have serious issues with your naming conventions, structure of your functions, invalid usage of reserved names and wrong values passed to parameters

First, naming coventions. Function names should be lowercase letters, should not start with a letter and words should be divided by underscores (`_`). The same goes for custom post type and taxonomy names. Drop your capital letters. The same goes for rewrite rules

Secondly, don't create multiple instances that should be hooked to the same function. Properly group your code together in **one** function, and add that one function to your intended hook, in this case `init`

Thirdly, don't use reserved names, even to rewrite slugs. It is confusing and might conflict later with the template hierarchy. In your case, you've use `category`, which is a reserved name.

Lastly, have a look at the codex for the correct values that should be passed to a particular parameter. `cat` excepts only category ID's, not slugs or name. BTW, you are making use of a custom taxonomy, so you should use the `tax_query` parameter and not the category parameters.

For reference

- [`register_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)
- [`register_taxonomy`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)
- [Reserved names](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms)
- [Coding Standards - Naming Conventions](http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/php/#naming-conventions)
- [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

**EDIT**

One thing I forgot to add, `wp_reset_query` is suppose to be used with `query_posts`, which you should never use. Whenever using `WP_Query` and `get_posts`, you need to reset your custom query with `wp_reset_postdata`

**EDIT 2**

You've missed a couple of points here that I spoke about. What is confusing is that you've changed a few things you've should have. Before I post code just a few extra things

- When you create a custom taxonomy, and you need to it to function like build-in categories, you need to set `hierarchical` to true. When you set it to false, your custom taxonomy behave like build-in post tags
- Whenever you create a "category" in a custom taxonomy, it is known as a term.
- Your taxonomy is called `project`, yet you pass `Initiatieffase` (which I think might be a term of the taxonomy `project` to the taxonomy parameter.
- When you set field in your `tax_query` to `slug`, you have to use the **slug** of your term in the `terms` parameter, **not the name** of the term.
- Your custom post type is called `project_post_type` but you pass `project` (which is your taxonomy name) to the `post_type` parameter in your custom query

This is how your code should look like

```
<?php
// Register Custom Post Type
function create_cpt_and_ct() {

    $labels1 = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Projects', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Project', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Project', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args1 = array(
        'label'               => __( 'project_post_type', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Project Description', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'              => $labels1,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', ),
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'project' ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_icon'           => get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/project-icon.png',
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
    );
    register_post_type( 'project_post_type', $args1 );

    $labels2 = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Projects', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Project', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Project', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Item Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove items', 'text_domain' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used items', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args2 = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels2,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'project', 'project_post_type', $args2 );

}

// Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'create_cpt_and_ct', 0 );


function theme_prefix_rewrite_flush() {
flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'theme_prefix_rewrite_flush' );
```

And for your `tax_query`

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'project_post_type',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'project',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'Initiatieffase' //THIS MUST BE YOUR TERM SLUG, NOT NAME
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); 
?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
    </li>
<?php 
endwhile; 

wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

**ADDITIONAL READING**

-[Debugging in Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

**EDIT 3**

For proper naming and the correct use of templates, go and check the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) in the codex. This should help you out a lot in future

Your single page would be single-{$post_type}.php which translates to single-project_post_type.php. Same goes for your archive page.

As for your custom taxonomy page, you can use taxonomy-$taxonomy.php which translates to taxonomy-project.php

Comment: Please see my update. This should work for you

Comment: thanks it worked lot of thanks you are really helpful guy thanks

Comment: sorry to bother you but last question what would be the name of single page template ? project-post-type-single.php or project-single.php ?

Comment: how can i give you feedback or appreciate you for helping me out ?

Comment: Look at the left hand side of my answer. There are a up/down vote arrow. Just below those arrows are a check mark. Click on that check mark. This will then go green, which gives me credit and shows that the question is resolved. Check out our [tour page](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) as well to get an idea of how the site works :-)

Comment: Hope you got my comment. For some reason comments doesn't pull through since the upgrade yesterday